# How create copy SYSDBA?

Tags: teradata

now I have 2 user, DBC and SYSDBA.

I want to create else 5 users with same rights as SYSDBA.

Please help to write script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is what you want?  Nevertheless, seems simple enough: grant sysdba to [username]

Just note that whenever they connect, they have to explicitly mention "as sysdba", and, in fact, they'll all be identified internally as SYS user.

Comment: role sysdba absent in Teradata

Comment: OP tagged the topic as Teradata and your answer is related to Oracle